# Vagrant up not working for laravel homestead 3.0.2

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

Used the new 'homestead make' command to make the Vagrantfile.

Afterwards, running 'vagrant up' results in this error:

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/testproject/Vagrantfile
Message: cannot load such file -- /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/testproject/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

Any idea what the issue may be? I am at a loss for this one.

Comment: can you paste your file ? Vagrantfile, yaml file ...